# how to upload images in a table field in my

Tags: mysql

Im creating a movie database in mysql. i need to store the images of the movie in a table in single field. pls help me out

Comment: The first question should be whether this is a good idea at all; normally, image files are better off stored in the file system. Secondly, you are not specifying a programming language that you want to do this with. You need to add much much more context and detail

Comment: store name of the image in db and store image in file system..

Comment: file system means any place on the drive ha. im just going to display the pics using qt. im not using any programing language to insert.i want to insert directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store images in your database, just store the references to them (file names or paths). If there will be more than one image per movie, then you will have a table representing this one-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_images (movie_id int, image varchar(255));
```

For each image, insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO movie_images (movie_id, image) VALUES (1, 'preview.png');
INSERT INTO movie_images (movie_id, image) VALUES (1, 'poster.png');
INSERT INTO movie_images (movie_id, image) VALUES (1, 'trailer.png');
```

Comment: I'm using qt4 to display the database.

Comment: The UI framework? What is that supposed to clarify?

Comment: just the file name can find the pic?

Comment: But the problem is im using ubuntu i have no idea how to get the exact path> i directly want to store image in the field –

Answer (score 0):

you can store the images in the db as BLOB. [This](http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/how-to-store-images-in-blob-field-312671.html) might help.

The other way (and my preferred one) would be to store the images in the file system and just store the name or the path of the images as string in the db so that you can fetch it later.

Comment: But the problem is im using ubuntu i have no idea how to get the exact path> i directly want to store image in the field